# Certain email does not show up in Outlook search results

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an issue with Outlook 2010. Some emails simply won't show in the search results. I'm trying, for instance, to search for the title of this email and it simply does not work no matter what I do - put the whole title (copy-pasted) or parts of it.

Searches for other emails work all-right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XP, you have to have Windows Search installed.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Why the heck this has been voted down?

Comment: The problem is still there, BTW - I just copy-pasted a certain text from subject to the search window and it found NOTHING.